# quasilinear partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given a PDE

$ f e^2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}- e f^2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + M_1 f^4 + M_2 f^2 + M_3=0 $

Note that $M_1$ , $M_2$ and $M_3$ are functions of $\cos (x-y)$ and $\sin (x-y)$

e is a constant

How could one solve this PDE ? Any suggestion

Comment: a method used for non-linear PDEs is a generalisation of fourier transform known as [inverse scattering method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_scattering_transform)

Comment: another one is approximate solution *about* a solution of the linearised PDE (in a sense of approximation or *perturbation*)

Comment: A general method to solve this kind of PDE is the so-called Lagrange-Charpit method which follows from the characteristics method. (See here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897299/initial-value-problem-for-non-linear-partial-differential-equation-y-x2-k-y-t/897605#897605) If you write down all the equalities, I'm afraid you come up with something completely unpleasant.

Comment: inspired by @Dmoreno ' comment, the [method of characteristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics), seems to be better suited for quasi-linear PDEs

Comment: Most certainly, the method of characteristics is what you want.